# Missing argument 2 for Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell::setItemLimit()

Tags: magento-1.8, product-list, php-5.4, pagination, up-sells

I get an exception Missing argument 2 for Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell::setItemLimit() but it only occurs when I have Magento Developer Mode enabled.

However, this occurs only when I have Magento DeveloperMode enabled.  I assume this has something to do with bad XML configuration data?  But I'm not sure exactly how to track down the source of the problem.

UPDATE: I need to open this back up for help as it turns out the fix (which should have been fixed) actually did not solve the warning message.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem by searching for all occurences of setItemLimit in the Magento .xml configuration files.   I found the offending XML element in catalog.xml for my template.

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
  <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type></action>
</block>
```

the setItemLimit is missing a 'limit' value.  I fixed with:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
  <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</block>
```

The people that created the skin for my site messed that up.

Aren't there any tools to analyze the Magento configuration files for accuracy rather than only finding this as a runtime error?

Comment: if this is now working feel free to accept this answer

Comment: It turns out this answer was wrong.    It definitely was missing configuration that should be there, but I am still getting an exception about a missing missing argument 2 error in upsell.php.